# How to store a a number and save it to a list only if a line comes a number of lines after

Tags: python

I have packets flowing through the network and I have the monitoring in a text file, so in the beginning I store the "header time" in a variable but save it in a list only if I found the a specific that says "UI SERVICE MATCH (HJ)" follows like 13 line after it, so it's find match after case.

The data is

```
         ******* DCS = 5    ************** 2016-02-05    13:29:13.58 ****
      From PC19 to PC02
      Network layer link
      ESTABLISH INDICATION (88H) 
         Channel class            
          - power number : 3 
          - Timeslot : 0
         Link supplier            
          - Shapi : 0
          - Channel type : Duplex
          - Normal prio
         L3 Information               
          UI SERVICE MATCH (HJ)
            UI SERVICE Type                  
            - channel establishment

             ******* DCS = 5    ************** 2016-02-05    13:29:18.79 ****
      From PC19 to PC02
      Network layer link
      ESTABLISH INDICATION (88H) 
         Channel class            
          - power number : 4 
          - Timeslot : 0
         Call Load                  
          - Slot:32  Busy:1     Access:1
```

The code is

```
fh = open("moni.txt")
elements = []
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if "******* DCS = 5" in line :
        U=line.split()
        Y = U[6]

    if 'UI SERVICE MATCH (HJ)' in line :
        elements.append(Y)

print elements
```

The output:

```
[]
```

The desired output:

```
['13:29:13.58']
```

Comment: have you considered iterating over your file in reverse?

Comment: I think you aren't reading the file's content correctly in the loop. To store the files content as a list of string lines, you should do `lines = fh.read().splitlines()` (before declaring the loop of course)

Comment: I guess you are only adding Y (your datetime) in `elements` if there is `'UI SERVICE MATCH (HJ)'` in the same line which is never the case (you could split your data by "block" for example, then fetch the datetime of a block if it contains the desired `'UI SERVICE MATCH (HJ)'`)

Comment: Your code looks like it should work.  Is `"moni.txt"` the correct file?

Comment: Yeah, I just ran it and it produces the desired output. Make sure the file is really where you're looking for it.

Comment: @SebasSBM:  `for line in openedfile:` is the preferred method for iterating over lines.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski Weird... I just tested that approach in python 2.7.3's interactive console and it just don't print anything. I'll keep trying just in case

Comment: @SebasSBM:  Nonetheless, your claim that OP needs to do `lines = fh.read().splitlines()` to fix his code is incorrrect.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski. If you say that, I believe you. This kind of loop is returning `str` objects, that's for sure. "Why printing these ones seems to destroy the `fh`'s content after looping it this way, and `print` statement in each iteration prints nothing?"  is what I am wondering right now... I will have to research about this approach

Comment: Hello and thanks everybody and special thanks to @mgc for supplying the answer :) it works

Comment: Works in mine. Check indentation if doing a copy/paste

Comment: @Will so you can get the only the desired value, what version of python you are using

Answer (score 2):

You can try to simplify your code with something like :

```
fh = open("moni.txt")
elements = []
# First split your file in block of data who belongs together :
for block in fh.read().split("******* DCS = 5    **************"):
    # Check if there is the desired string :
    if 'UI SERVICE MATCH (HJ)' in block :
        # Save the time :
        elements.append(block.split()[1])

print(elements)
# ['13:29:13.58']
```